# White-space:pre-wrap not aligned on first line

Tags: html, css

I have the following html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <style> 
  p.test {
   width: 11em; 
   border: 1px solid #000000;
   word-wrap: break-word;
   white-space: pre-wrap;
 }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <p class="test"> This paragraph contains a very long word: thisisaveryveryveryveryveryverylongword.   The long word will break and wrap to the next line.</p>
 </body>
```

When the page is displayed, the first line of the text shift by one letter.
[image]

If I change to "white-space:pre-line", the display will not show white space.  How to make the first line aligned with the rest of the text?

Comment: Could you provide a snippet or fiddle?

Comment: I do not know how to provide a fiddle. I google it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Remove the space...

Change

`<p class="test"> This`

to

`<p class="test">This`

```css
p.test {
  width: 11em;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

```html
<p class="test">This paragraph contains a very long word: thisisaveryveryveryveryveryverylongword. The long word will break and wrap to the next line.</p>
```

Comment: I gave a bad example. You are correct that there is an extra space there that I did not notice. Although my intend was to solve a different problem related to format a cell in angular material Mat-table. Your solution to this problem is correct.

Answer (score 6):

instead of `white-space: pre-wrap` use the css property `white-space: pre-line`

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript, instead of CSS white-space or word-break

```
var ss = "This paragraph contains a very long word:  thisisaveryveryveryveryveryverylongword. The long word will break and wrap to the next line.";

document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = ss.replace(/\n/g, '<br/>');
```

or

```
document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = ss.replace(/\n/g, '<br>\n');
```

Answer (score -1):

Just use `white-space: normal` or not `white-space` at all.

```css
p.test {
  width: 11em;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  white-space: normal;
}
```

```html
<p class="test"> This paragraph contains a very long word: thisisaveryveryveryveryveryverylongword. The long word will break and wrap to the next line.</p>
```

Comment: I do not want delete any white spaces. Your solution deletes white spaces.

Comment: This only delete the extra white spaces, like the first one as you asked. The rest keep untouched. https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp